# Is a signal caught if a thread is waiting on a mutex?

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, signals, mutex

I have a thread blocked on a mutex. The application also has custom signal handlers, set using `sigaction`. If the thread that receives a catchable signal is blocked on a mutex, will the signal handler be called, or will it be blocked until the mutex is released?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably it will depend on implementation, in `pthread` for example signal handler will be executed and then thread will wait for mutex upon handler return:

> ### man pthread_mutex_lock
>
> If a signal is delivered to a thread waiting for a mutex, upon return
>   from  the  signal  handler  the
>          thread shall resume waiting for the mutex as if it was not interrupted.

Comment: Doh! Spent my time looking at signal docs, not pthread docs. Thanks very much :-)

Comment: Likewise there isn't a return value (errno) of EINTR for pthread lock calls.

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html#:~:text=These%20functions%20shall%20not%20return%20an%20error%20code%20of%20%5BEINTR%5D.